# Create ManagedAppPolicies Beta Microsoft Graph API not working with application permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, intune

I am trying to create intune app protection policy. I tried below APIs to do it, but none of it works :
POST /managedAppPolicies/ - while creating managed Policy (tried for both iOS and Android)
- Returns 401 Unauthorized.

Sample Create Managed App Policy Request:

```
POST /managedAppPolicies/  
Request Body :
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#managedAppPolicies/$entity",
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.iosManagedAppProtection",
  "displayName": "Test IOS Policy",
  "description": "test",
  "periodOfflineBeforeAccessCheck": "PT12H",
  "periodOnlineBeforeAccessCheck": "PT30M",
  "allowedInboundDataTransferSources": "allApps",
  "allowedOutboundDataTransferDestinations": "allApps",
  "organizationalCredentialsRequired": false,
  "allowedOutboundClipboardSharingLevel": "allApps",
  "dataBackupBlocked": true,
  "deviceComplianceRequired": true,
  "managedBrowserToOpenLinksRequired": false,
  "saveAsBlocked": false,
  "periodOfflineBeforeWipeIsEnforced": "P90D",
  "pinRequired": true,
  "maximumPinRetries": 5,
  "simplePinBlocked": false,
  "minimumPinLength": 4,
  "pinCharacterSet": "any",
  "allowedDataStorageLocations": [
    "oneDriveForBusiness",
    "sharePoint"
  ],
  "contactSyncBlocked": false,
  "printBlocked": false,
  "fingerprintBlocked": false,
  "targetedSecurityGroupIds": [  "valid directory group id 1",
    "valid directory group id 2" ],
  "appDataEncryptionType": "whenDeviceLocked"
}
```

Response : 401 Unauthorized

```
{
  "error": {
"code": "UnknownError",
"message": "{\"ErrorCode\":\"Forbidden\",\"Message\":\"An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: f932cecd-028f-42ea-9464-abf6e04f9ede - Url: https://fef.amsua0502.manage.microsoft.com/MAMAdmin/MAMAdminFEService/managedAppPolicies?api-version=2016-06-16 - CustomApiErrorPhrase: \",\"Target\":null,\"Details\":null,\"InnerError\":null,\"InstanceAnnotations\":[]}",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "f932cecd-028f-42ea-9464-abf6e04f9ede",
  "date": "2017-03-03T17:44:10"
}
```

}
}

I've created a WebApp on azure portal and also have given DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All permission to my app. The access_token was programmatically obtained by using

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/oauth2/token
```

where it can be acquired in application's context rather than providing user credentials on web form (User Grant Method)

P.S. I've made sure the access_token generated from clientid and secret is correct as the same token works when used to search groups on azure.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName,%27test users%27)
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that the user is given intune license. Could you try granting license to your RBAC-ed user?

Comment: My User has 3 licenses, Enterprise Mobility+Security E5, Intune and Office365 Enterprise E3. still it doesn't work. @alemeshet Alemu

Answer (score 0):

I work on the Microsoft Intune team, specifically on the integration between Microsoft Intune and Microsoft Graph.

I was able to locate the error message in our logging, and based on your post it appears that you are trying to use an app only token (no user credentials), at the current time the Microsoft Intune APIs exposed via Microsoft Graph only support app + user tokens (user credentials required).

Hope this helps

Peter